How to create rv_histogram from known probability density function values
Let's say there is a distribution, and all what is known about the distribution is the value of its probability density function in a small range(e.g. from 0.0 to 0.001).
Then, I want to use statistical functions in scipy to describe the distribution, and I found there is a function called scipy.stats.rv_histogram which seems can be used because everything I known about the distribution is the something like a array of histograms.
The method says that the first parameter:

In particular, the return value of numpy.histogram is accepted.

Following the guide, I tried to call the numpy.histogram method, however I found that it actually asks for count number but the probability density for each bin, viz. there are 123 elements but the probability density is 0.1 in the range from 0.0 to 0.001. And the parameter density controls the output but the input.
May I know are there some other solutions in such a case that only the value of probability density function is known please?
Take the following distribution as an example:

The height of each bin is known and also the width of each bin is a constant. Here, the height of each bin is the probability density of the distribution but the count number in the small range.

What methods do you need the distribution object to have? (i.e. what do you want to do with it?) Is it actually a discrete distribution with the PMF known at all points, do you want to interpolate the PDF between known points, or do you have a function that describes the PDF? What happens outside the domain on which the PDF is defined?

Could you also further clarify what you have exactly? Maybe with some dummy data similar to yours? Maybe also add a plot of your data? If the only thing you know is that "the probability density is 0.1 in the range from 0.0 to 0.001", this would be much too meager to tell something useful about the full distribution.
